# What is MATLAB equivalent of Java Vector class?

Tags: matlab

Java has [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class that can be used to dynamically store Strings e.g.

`Vector<String> vex = new Vector<String>();`

and then I can add elements dynamically. What is the MATLAB equivalent to this Vector class?

Comment: Pretty much ***ALL*** of matlabs variable types dynamically grow like a Java vector... e.g. `A = {'one', 'two'};` `A{end+1} = 'three';`

Comment: Thanks @Dan! Can you give examples of any other MATLAB class types than cell array which behave this way?

Comment: can you give me an example of one that doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings, use a cell array:

```
 a = {};
```

Add to it dynamically by concatenating other cell arrays:

```
a = [a { 'foo', 'bar' }]
```

or by implicitly assigning beyond the cell array's bounds:

```
a{end+1} = 'foo';
```

Note that like all other matlab arrays, cell arrays have a shape, so beware of shape incompatibilities when concatenating.

Comment: "cell array have shape?" Can you please explain that?

Comment: `{'foo' 'bar'}` is a 1-by-2 (one row, two column) array.  It can be concatenated with the empty cell array `{}` and with other 1-by-n cell arrays, but not with (say) a 2-by-1 array.  This idea is absolutely fundamental to Matlab, so I'd recommend looking for a basic Matlab tutorial if this is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that the dimensions of arguments must agree while applying any operator... the word "shape" confused me a bit.